# Look for a function/formula which doesn't accept an argument whose type is Empty

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In general, a empty cell in Excel can be implicitly converted to `0` (`Double` type), `FALSE` (`Boolean` type), `""` (`String` type) to avoid functions from not working. For instance, given `A1` is empty, `=-A1` returns `0`, `=IF(A1,TRUE,FALSE)` returns `FALSE`, `=LEN(A1)` returns `0`...

However, I am looking for a function or formula, to which applying an empty cell returns an error. `=5/A1` is an example, because it returns `#DIV/0!`, but I consider `#DIV/0!` a very special case. I would hope to find a function or formula which doesn't accept an argument whose type is `Empty`.

I would hope this kind of formula to be simple and really used in practice... (though it seems unlikely, otherwise it would be easy to find out...)

Could anyone help?

**Edit 1**: Per the comment, this is indeed for documentation. I need to find the most convincing examples to show that my solution solves real and basic problems in practice...

Comment: Per you comment on your other question, I would suggest letting people know this is for documentation and that you are looking for examples for said documentation - it will make it clearer that you are looking for examples of certain solutions as opposed to an answer to a particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do something with `ISBLANK()`  which returns TRUE if the cell is blank and FALSE if it isn't. You could do `IF(ISBLANK(A1),NA(),A1)` for example.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, that does fullfil the requirement, but it seems really artificial to create the error...

Comment: But you ARE creating an error - excel is quite happy with blanks.